# NWJS Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

Tags: javascript, header, xmlhttprequest

Hello every one i am trying to work with the SubDb api. This api requires to set some user agent headers to work.

Docs:

[image]

I tried to set the headers this way:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'http://api.thesubdb.com/?action=search&hash=edc1981d6459c6111fe36205b4aff6c2');
request.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','SubDB/1.0 (testapp/0.0.1; https://github.com/maantje)');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
    obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(obj);

  }
};

request.send();
```

But i get 'Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"' and like the docs said i get a 412 since it refused to set the header.
GET http://api.thesubdb.com/?action=search&hash=edc1981d6459c6111fe36205b4aff6c2 412 (Precondition Failed)

How can i correctly set the header?

Here is the working code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: 'api.thesubdb.com',
  path: '/?action=search&hash=edc1981d6459c6111fe36205b4aff6c2',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
        'Content-length':0,
        'User-Agent': 'SubDB/1.0 (testapp/0.0.1; https://github.com/maantje)'
    }
};

var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
  //console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

  // Buffer the body entirely for processing as a whole.
  var bodyChunks = [];
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    // You can process streamed parts here...
    bodyChunks.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', function() {
    var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
    console.log('BODY: ' + body);
    obj = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(obj);

    // ...and/or process the entire body here.
  })
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[XMLHttpRequest](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-setrequestheader()-method) doesn't allow you to set the User-Agent header since it's one of the [forbidden headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name).

To be able to work with the SubDb api you could write your own script where you would send the requests. That scripts then sends the correct headers to the SubDb api and you then pass the response to the client.

With php you can for example use [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or with python you could use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to set the user agent header.

Comment: Thanks for the information! do you know any alternative that does allow met to set the user-agent?

Comment: You can't do this on the browser directly, unless you change the browsers user agent (using plugin or developer tools).

Using server side for example [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) allows you to set whatever user agent you like.

Comment: Managed to do it with the node_module http